# View Model with a List

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

If I construct a View Model with a List like this:

```
public class ProductsViewModel
{
    public bool ProductBool { get; set; }
    public string ProductString { get; set; }
    public int ProductInteger { get; set; }
    public List<Product> ProductList { get; set; }
}
```

it works fine. But I've seen code that constructs a similar Model like so:

```
public class ProductsViewModel
{
    public bool ProductBool { get; set; }
    public string ProductString { get; set; }
    public int ProductInteger { get; set; }
    public List<Product> ProductList { get; set; }

    public ProductsViewModel()
    {
        this.ProductList = new List<Product>();
    }
}
```

What does the extra contructor element actually do?

Comment: It just initializes `ProductList` as an empty collection (so its not `null`). So now you can do - `var model = new ProductsViewModel(); model Products.Add(new Product());` and it will not throw and exception (otherwise you would need to add `model.ProductList = new List<Product>();` before the `Add()` method.

Comment: I think not necessary to instantiated in product list in constructor, Define object  like `List<Product> ProductList  objProductList = new List<Product> ProductList();`  before the `Add()` in List.

Comment: @Prabhat that makes no sense. The OP is showing a property; you're showing how to initialize a new local variable (and I guess you're trying to assign that to the `ProductList` property). The addition of a local variable to initialize a class member is what is not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create an object of the class ProductsViewModel with the statement:

```
ProductsViewModel obj = new ProductsViewModel();
```

It automatically instantiate the ProductList. The values in obj now are:

```
ProductBool = false;ProductString = null;ProductInteger = 0;ProductList = new ProductList();
```

If you write `obj.ProductList.Count()` it will give 0

If you remove this constructor or the statement inside the constructor and create object of Class ProductsViewModel as created above. The values in obj will be:

```
ProductBool = false;ProductString = null;ProductInteger = 0;ProductList =null
```

If you write `obj.ProductList.Count()` it will give

> Exception of NullReference